# ViewChild or Local Reference to external npm module component

Tags: angular7, viewchild, simplebar

I am using SimpleBar (https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplebar-angular) in my project.

Since I would like to modify some styles of that component, so I added a local reference in the template,

```
<ngx-simplebar [options]="simpleBarOptions" #simplebar></ngx-simplebar>
```

and viewchild like this in my Typescript file:

```
@ViewChild('simplebar') simplebar: ElementRef;
```

However, when I try to log it in console with this code. It returns undefined. Why is that? If I local reference to a `<div>` directly, then it works fine.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('log: ' + this.simplebar.nativeElement);
  }
```

The component code I see in Chrome (F12 mode) is as follows:

```
<ngx-simplebar _ngcontent-opy-c3="" data-simplebar="init" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]">
  <div class="simplebar-wrapper" style="margin: 0px;">
  ......
  </div>
</ngx-simplebar>
```

Many thanks!

Angus

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@ViewChild(SimplebarAngularComponent, { static: false }) simplebar: ElementRef<SimplebarAngularComponent>;
```